# cannot print database records in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am trying to print Database records. 
When I run the code below from retrieve_all.html

I can print my sent name but can't print the attachment records. all am seeing in the command prompt is

```
select 'attachments',*From 'attachments'

my name: is Nancy More
my all: #<Attachment::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x090d4820>
```

it seems that **@attachment** variable is empty. Any idea on what is going on
I deally I should also be printing id, filename etc.

```
print('fid: ', @attachment.id)
print('fname: ', @attachment.filename)
```

**here is the code.**

```
def retrieve_all
    name = 'nancy More'
    print('my name is: ', name)
    @attachment = Attachment.all
    print('my all: ', @attachment)

    # providing that gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'  in the gemfile and display records in json
    #render json: @attachment = Attachment.all


end
```

Comment: Try `Attachment.count` if 0 then is empty.

Comment: Attachment.count displays rows count of 38 which corresponds to 38 rows in the database. thus not empty. please Sir what do I do next

Comment: It is working exactly as you have coded it to work. `@attachment` is an `ActiveRecord_Relation` because you set it as such using `Attachment,all`. And that is wasn't you are displaying.

Comment: @NancyMooree as stated by @jvillian, you are just printing the `activerecord`. What do you want to print exactly?

Comment: I have id and filename column in the database. I need to print them eg attachment.id, attachment.filename. and then finally display all the response in json as can be seen in the code below render json: attachment = Attachment.all

Comment: Try using `inspect` => `puts @attachment.inspect`

Comment: @Deepak, I try to query the records based on Id  like below. I can get the result and it will work  but If want to get all the result no way.                                                             
    attachment = Attachment.where(:id => '1').first
    attachment = Attachment.find(1)

Comment: @Deepak. I have tried the inspect command also. this is what I got   #<ACTIVERecord::Relation[#<Attachment id: 1,
filename: "1.png"> <Attachment id: 2,
filename: "2.png">

Comment: Is there anyway I can loop and print the result may be that is what it need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code posted is working fine. The issue was caused by images that was stored in the database as binary.